# What methods are there for (graphically) scaling elements on a web page in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm making a graphical JavaScript application that has elements rotating and moving across the screen (using CSS `transform` for Mozilla/WebKit browsers and `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix` for Internet Explorer.)

Now I want to scale the container of these elements (including its child elements) so that I can simulate zooming out. This works fine using `transform` for Mozilla/WebKit, but the problem with Internet Explorer is that the transformation matrix doesn't appear to be applied to child elements that have `position: absolute`.

My only option now appears to be to alter the positions of every child element to adhere to the scaling I want, then apply scaling to their individual transformation matrices...

I'm just wondering, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `zoom` css property? It is commonly used as a hack for float clearing, but originally it was intended for scaling elements ad groups of elements.